# Position two divs in a jQuery UI tabs properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am a noob CSS programmer and I need a little help. Here are two screenshots:

[image: jquery ui tabs 1]

and

[image: jquery ui tabs 2]

I need to position the tree and the TinyMCE editor which exist in divs properly in the tab area. AS you can see the bottom tab border is very high instead of below the tree and the editor.

Here is my HTML code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Demo";
}

<link href="../../Plugins/jqueryui/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="../../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Plugins/jstree/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Plugins/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Plugins/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h2>Demo</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Select a language: </legend>

    <label for="mk-MK">MK</label>
    <input type="radio" name="langid" value="mk-MK" id="mk-MK" checked>

    <label for="en-US">EN</label>
    <input type="radio" name="langid" value="en-US" id="en-US">

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="t1" href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
            <li><a id="t2" href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a id="t3" href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <select name="domainSelect" id="domainSelect">
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <select name="surveySelect" id="surveySelect">
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="clFreqText"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <select name="clPeriodSelect" id="clPeriodSelect">
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <select name="clYearSelect" id="clYearSelect">
            </select>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div class="treeBlock">
                <div id="jstree_div"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="editorBlock">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="10" id="textEditor">Next, get a free TinyMCE Cloud API key!</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">

        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Next" id="nextBtn" />
        <input type="button" value="Previous" id="prevBtn" />
    </p>
    <p id="statusMsg"></p>
    <p id="errorsMsg"></p>

</fieldset>

<script src="../../Plugins/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Plugins/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Plugins/jstree/jstree.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Plugins/tinymce/theme.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- other scripts -->
```

And style.css contains:

```
fieldset {
      border: 0;
}

label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.overflow {
      height: 200px;
}

.treeBlock 
{
    border: 1px solid Grey;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
}

.editorBlock 
{
    overflow: auto;
    float: right;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why the [jquery ui tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) are not of the proper size?

Note: I am coding with MVC 4/C# and Razor, so the file extension is "cshtml" fro my View

Here is what happens when I change the width to 50%, 50%.
The "Next" and "Previous" buttons should be below.

[image: jquery ui tabs 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed my html a bit:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="t1" href="#tabs-1">Info</a></li>
            <li><a id="t2" href="#tabs-2">Content</a></li>
            <li><a id="t3" href="#tabs-3">Summary</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <select name="domainSelect" id="domainSelect">
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <select name="surveySelect" id="surveySelect">
            </select>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div class="treeBlock">
                <div id="jstree_div"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="editorBlock">
                <input type="text" value="" id="editorTitleTxt" disabled="disabled"/>
                <div class="editor">
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="10" id="textEditor">Next, get a free TinyMCE Cloud API key!</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="10" id="summaryText" disabled="disabled">Next, get a free TinyMCE Cloud API key!</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
fieldset {
      border: 0;
}

label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.overflow {
      height: 200px;
}

.treeBlock 
{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 38%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid Grey;
    margin: 5px;
}

.editorBlock 
{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 5px;
}

#editorTitleTxt 
{
    width: 98%;
    font-weight:bold;    
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: tabs jquery ui]

Answer (score 0):

In `tabs-2`'s css rules add the following rule:

`overflow:auto`

This will fix the height rendering issue due to the floated children divs.

Comment: Well... it doesn't work. the "clearfix" div inside the "editorBlock" div or as a third child of  "tabs-2"?

Comment: As a child of `tabs-2` right before `tabs-2`'s closing tag.

Comment: @Vlad I'm sorry my first answer was somewhat misguided due to how early in the morning it is right now. I fixed it so it should work for you. Sorry about that. I was thinking of two different CSS fixes and I ended up merging the two, which won't work. This will though.

Answer (score 0):

Try a table with `width:100%` and the columns repsectively 40%,20%,40%.